# using Global Temporary table in a Job

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i, temp-tables

I am working on a  PL-SQL stored procedure which will run depending on a daily job.
in the stored procedure I am trying to use a global temporary table like that:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE A_Table 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS 
AS SELECT * from B_Table
```

and then I will try to create index like that:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_a ON A_Table (id)
```

I have two problems:

1. The Table That I have created is always empty: so all the calculation in the stored procedure will be zero.
2. when I am trying to create the index I got this error:

   ORA-14452:attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use

any advice please ??

Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

1. Any data put in a temporary table will only be there for the rest of the session (or transaction if you specify `on commit delete rows`). If you want to store data between sessions use a normal table.
2. Close the session that uses the temporary table, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you are creating the temporary table but presumably you have created it once and are not trying to recreate it every time the plsql code runs and also the index definition can remain on the temp table - this also doesnt need to be created every time you run the code.

A global temporary table has a static definition - you just create it and it is there but it generates no redo/undo and the data contained in it is only visible to the session that populates it.

```
    SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.4.2 - Production on Wed Oct 26 01:22:30 2011

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

    SQL> create global temporary table test (name varchar2(20));

    Table created.

    SQL> insert into test values ('one');

    1 row created.

    SQL> insert into test values ('two');

    1 row created.

    SQL> select * from test;

    NAME
    --------------------
    one
    two
```

Then in another session

```
    SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.4.2 - Production on Wed Oct 26 01:23:17 2011

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

    SQL> select * from test;

    no rows selected

    SQL> insert into test values ('three');

    1 row created.

    SQL> select * from test;

    NAME
    --------------------
    three
```

back in the first session
        SQL> commit;

```
    Commit complete.

    SQL> select * from test;

    no rows selected

    SQL> drop table test;
    drop table test
               *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already
    in use
```

Because we have inserted data in our second session, we cant do anything to the temp table
until we commit in the second session, then the drop succeeds

You have the option to have the contents cleared for the session that created it either when you commit (on commit delete rows) or to keep the data until the session is terminates (on commit preserve rows).

Answer (score 0):

1. The table you have created may be not empty, but only for session, that fills it. Each session has, so to say, it's own instance of temporary table. That's main feature of temporary tables, by the way.
2. Modification of temp. table is impossible, while any session that had ever used it  is alive (may not be active)